# how can I prove this $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4k^{2}-2k}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

How can I prove the following equation?:

$$s=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4k^{2}-2k}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}$$

Simplifying both terms of the equation:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4k^{2}-2k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)2k} =(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k})$$

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k})=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k})$$

Now we have:

$$s=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k})=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}\color{blue}{+}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}\color{blue}{-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}})$$

How can I continue?

Comment: How? By induction, of course

Comment: This is, perhaps, a slightly more difficult induction problem than your typical "practice exercise," but you still really should share your thoughts on what you have tried and where you have gotten stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A non-inductive proof ,
$$ S= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4k^2-2k}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(k)} $$
$$ S= \frac{1}{2}\left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{(2k-1)}-\frac{1}{k} \right) 
$$
$$S= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k} $$
Also it is easy to see that,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k} $$
Subtracting the 2 equations we get,
$$ S =\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} - 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k} =\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} $$
Hence, proved.

Comment: That is the way I would have proceeded.  +1

Comment: Hello Tushant Mittal, Thank you very much!!

However I do not see equality:
$$s=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k})=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k})$$

Comment: @DarioGutierrez Which equality is the problem:first or second?

Comment: the second:
 $$ S =\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} - 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k} =\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} $$

Where did you get that $- 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}$  ?

Comment: Just subtract the 2 equations

Answer (score 3):

Let's do a cute induction on $n$:

For $n = 1$, we have $\frac{1}{4 - 2} = \frac{1}{2}$, so the claim holds.

Assume $n > 1$ and the claim holds for $n - 1$. Then $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{4k^2 - 2k} = \frac{1}{4n^2 - 2n} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{4k^2 - 2k} = \frac{1}{4n^2 - 2n} + \sum_{k = n}^{2(n  -1)} \frac{1}{k}$$
by the induction hypothesis. So we only need to show that $\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{4n^2 - 2n}$, which is just a direct computation.

Answer (score 0):

The core part of the induction argument spelled out more explicitly:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{2i(2i-1)}&= \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{2i(2i-1)}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)(2k+1)}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k}\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)(2k+1)}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=k+2}^{2k+2}\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k+2}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)(2k+1)}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=k+2}^{2k+2}\frac{1}{i}+\frac{2(2k+1)-2(k+1)-(2k+1)}{2(k+1)(2k+1)}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)(2k+1)}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=k+2}^{2k+2}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{2(k+1)(2k+1)}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)(2k+1)}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=k+2}^{2k+2}\frac{1}{i}.
\end{align}